# Hibernate createQuery() throws ClassCastException, Transformer doesn't help

Tags: hibernate, classcastexception

Trying to SELECT an entity using Using Hibernate 3.6 and MySQL5.1 but I keep getting a ClassCastException.

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "USER" )
public class User {
   @Id
   @Column(name= "user_id")
   private Long userId;

   @OneToOne()
   @JoinColumn(name="status_id")
   protected UserStatusType userStatusType;

   @OneToOne()
   @JoinColumn(name="region_id")
   protected Region region;


@Entity
@Table( name = "REGION" )
public class Region   
   @Id
   @Column(name = "region_id")
   private Long regionId


@Entity
@Table( name = "USER_STATUS_TYPE" )
public class UserStatusType  
   @Id
   @Column(name = "type_id")
   private Long typeId
```

When attempting to use HQL in createQuery() I keep getting a ClassCastException:

```
session.beginTransaction();
User user = (User)session.createQuery(
   "from User u, UserStatusType ust, Region r "
   + " where u.userId = ? and u.userStatusType.typeId = ust.typeId"
   + " and u.region.regionId = r.regionId")
   .setLong(0, 42L)                     
   .uniqueResult();


 java.lang.ClassCastException:
[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.scd.dao.entity.User
```

I tried using setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(User.class)), but that gave me a NullPointerException.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: will you kindly accept an answer for your question? That's how it works here on stackoverflow. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If `FROM` clause contains several entities, and you need only one of them, specify it in `SELECT`:

```
User user = (User)session.createQuery(
    "select u "
    + "from User u, UserStatusType ust, Region r "
    + " where u.userId = ? and u.userStatusType.typeId = ust.typeId"
    + " and u.region.regionId = r.regionId")
   .setLong(0, 42L)
   .uniqueResult();
```

Otherwise you'll get the tuple of entities as `Object[]`.

If you actually need eager fetching instead of inner join, use `JOIN FETCH`:

```
User user = (User)session.createQuery(
    "from User u "
    + "join fetch u.userStatusType join fetch u.region "
    + " where u.userId = ?")
   .setLong(0, 42L)
   .uniqueResult();
```

Comment: slightly faster and more detailed answer :)

Comment: I got that to work, thx, but why does Hibernate execute 3 separate select statements for this query? A single statement would perform better. I turned on trace debugging and I see a SELECT for User, UserStatusType, and Region.

Comment: Got it working, see https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1010000&p=2442641#p2442641

Comment: +1  This is one of those obvious answers that, once found, makes you feel like a moron that you didn't already know it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do so  is:

```
Query query = session.createQuery(queryString).addEntity(<Class Name>.class);
<Class Name> obj = (<Class Name>)query.uniqueResult();
```

Finally it worked for me try it...

Answer (score 0):

try

```
session.beginTransaction();
User user = (User)session.createQuery(
   "select u from User u, UserStatusType ust, Region r "
   + " where u.userId = ? and u.userStatusType.typeId = ust.typeId"
   + " and u.region.regionId = r.regionId")
   .setLong(0, 42L)                     
   .uniqueResult();
```

Comment: That worked to eliminate the ClassCastException, thx, but I see that Hibernate is using 3 separate SELECT statements to build the entity; that's too many database hits for something that should require a single SELECT. How do I force it to hit the database only once?

Comment: Check this out too, https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1010000&p=2442641#p2442641

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue by adding `.addEntity(User.class)` in the end of the query. For example :

```
session.beginTransaction();
User user = (User)session.createQuery(
   "from User u, UserStatusType ust, Region r "
   + " where u.userId = ? and u.userStatusType.typeId = ust.typeId"
   + " and u.region.regionId = r.regionId")
   .setLong(0, 42L)                     
   .uniqueResult().addEntity(User.class);
```